# How to dynamically load Content in Div with Jquery? (Code given)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to have a overlay over my content site. So if somebody clicks on a link a article is loaded into the covering overlay Div

Everything is working fine except the output is not working properly.

```
<script language="javascript">

    $( ".iddd" ).click(function() {
    var aid = $(this).prop('id');
    $('#overlaycontent').load('http://www.example.com/overlay.php', { id: aid });

    });
```

Test PHP Script:

```
<?php 

include ("config.php");
$ID = $_POST['id'];

echo $ID;

?>
```

That´s how my links are placed:

```
<a class="iddd" href="#overlay" id="6337cab172">
```

The id should be loaded into the script so I can access my articles but i guess the Jquery is not working properly.

I looked at this [overlay with dynamic php content the right way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38779042/overlay-with-dynamic-php-content-the-right-way)

but still it doesnt post the ID properly!

Comment: What kind of error message do you get?

Comment: No error at all, at least in Firefox Debugger. Is it maybe serverside error?

Comment: Put the .click into the ready state so that it binds the event handler to the element after the DOM is fully loaded in by the browser. https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Now it loads but doesnt post the ID to the PHP Script, is the syntax of the jquery script right?

Comment: It could be that you are using `.prop('id')` instead of `.attr('id')`...

Comment: attr is deprecated, i already looked it up

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is in `config.php` and if missing that could cause your problem, but to include a file, you don't use parenthesis, but only quotes, so, instead of

```
include ("config.php");
```

just

```
include "config.php";
```

Comment: Parens may not be needed (and still work just fine if they exist). Having them isn't his problem.

Comment: yep, thank you sir :) Is it possible to write a function so i just need to put the id as a parameter and it automatically puts it in my overlay div?